# Scrolling camera with a tile map stored in JSON and PNG

Tags: camera, sdl2, tiled, json, png

I'm trying to get a scrolling camera into my SDL2 game and I'd like some advice. The way I'm implementing my map is as follows:

I use a tileset to build a map in the Tiled map editor, and I'm exporting it as both a png for the map image and a json file as a representation of the tile map. I know there are tmx parsers for SDL2 and C++, but until I figure out how to use them, I'm using the method listed above just to have something I can see and test.

Given this, would I have to scroll the png and the tile map representation in the json file, or would I only have to scroll the png? Many of the tutorials I have seen implement a scrolling camera by having a tile object/struct with an `x` and `y` coordinate data member that can be changed, but I don't think I can apply that to my json-png situation.

If anyone understands how SDL handles json files that come from the Tiled map editor, I'd really appreciate any advice. Thank you all!

Comment: Normally a camera scroll would be implemented not by moving each tile/object in your world, but by changing a transform/offset applied "just in time" before rendering, like a camera matrix. The map stays stationary and the camera "object" moves in relation to it.